# Retrieve count related lookup value using REST in SharePoint 2016

Tags: rest, sharepoint, count, lookup

I am following this post:
http://pawansatope.blogspot.com/2012/01/how-to-create-count-related-lookup.html
Now I want to get the same results(i.e DepartmentTitle and NbOfEmployees) values programatically using the REST api.

I've tried different variations of:

/items$select=Title,NbOfEmployees/...&$expand=NbOfEmployees
but haven't got any luck.

Has anyone tried this?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created the lookup field "NbOfEmployees" (Department(Count Related) to Employee Data list like this:

[image]

This is the two list data:

[image]

[image]

Then for NbOfEmployees field (Department count), directly get in Rest API:

```
http://sp2016/_api/web/lists/getbyTitle('Department')/items?$select=NbOfEmployeesId,Title
```

[image]

Actually, this value is the real count value for department, no need to expand in Rest.

Comment: Thanks, but that is not the case, I am using some other lists with no spaces in the columns' names and my display names match the internal names. I providede the link for reference only. It will not work as you wrote it, the $expand keyword is mandatory in order to select a lookup field.

Comment: what is the detailed column name you are using ? I tested based on your link in original question, No of Employee is a Int number column, not lookup field....

Comment: You can firstly check all the field internal name with /items endpoint, if it is a lookup field, expand like this blog:  https://diplaxmic.wordpress.com/2017/09/15/working-with-expand-and-lookup-fields-in-sharepoint-2013/

Comment: Jerry, please read carefully the post I mentioned, especially step 4 - the nb of employees is a special type of lookup field in SharePoint, called a count related lookup field. There does't seem to be a way to retrieve it with only one web service call.

Comment: @AdrianGanea, yes, this is a lookup field, but in Rest Response data, it is return the  valid count data with int type, please check my updated reply later.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time! It's working as you suggested in the edit - the trick is to add "Id" at the end of the internal field name. Many thanks!